# Occasionally missing new files from Subversion

Tags: svn

Here is our scenario:

Developer A checks in changes which include new files files.  Developer B does an update and all of a sudden, stuff breaks because files are missing.  Developer B tries another update, nothing is pulled in, so he calls Developer A.  Developer A says: "Hey, I checked them in, are you blind?"  Only when Developer B uses the TortiseSVN Repo Browser does he see that, indeed new files are available.  The fix is to 'update item to revision in TortiseSVN Repo Browser.  Even if Developer B updates through TortoiseSVN in explorer or the Subversive client in Eclipse, he can't see the new files.  We also can't see the file via the SVN command line client in Cygwin.

It doesn't happen all the time, and we can't seem to reproduce it at will.  But when it does, it's highly annoying.

Comment: Are you using any sort of Subversion externals, to include a directory from one project in another?

Comment: What OS is your team developing on?

Comment: I suppose you're using the newest version of the clients? I don't think there's need for cygwin in order to use the command line btw. On the command line, if you type `svn --version` what does that give you?

Comment: How did you check out the working copy? There is a setting to specify how deep you want the working copy to be, if it is set to "Only this item" (check the checkout dialog for TortoiseSVN), new files and folders in the repository won't make it to the working copy. You should try checking out a fresh copy and making it "Fully recursive", see if that helps.

Comment: I've had similar irregularities happen when I duplicated a checked-out directory (i.e. with all the metadata) and started filling the duplicate with files. Could it be something in that direction?

Comment: I highly doubt it, there's nothing on the server that tracks which working copies you have checked out, which means that if you duplicate a local working copy to a new directory, they're equally good, or bad. In other words, I don't think the duplication had any adverse effect on either the original or the duplicate.

Comment: No, I mean taking directory A and copy+pasting it as directory B (because it's the new copy of a module you need to modify a bit, for example). This screws up version control because the Meta info gets copied, too, but it's still related to directory A.

Comment: No, it is not, the meta information is local, it does not contain an absolute path to the working copy, so the duplicated metadata would be valid for the duplicated working copy.

Comment: We are using Windows. I just threw in the Cygwin because that's what we used -- our workstation guys do not give us a "native" svn command line client. But in Cygwin, we have a world that we control :)

That said, we usually check code in and out with Eclipse/Subversive  but do major stuff with TortiseSVN.  All clients and server is 1.6.x, with varying values for x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [FAQ](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#incompleteupdate) entry.

Comment: We're using "TortoiseSVN 1.6.5, Build 16974 - 32 Bit , 2009/08/20 08:13:46" but the Update to Revision is what always works.

Again, this happens intermittently but enough where it has become an issue. When it crops up again, we will look closer at it.

Comment: This happened in our environment. We had different versions of clients and different kinds of clients (TortoiseSVN, Ankh). It realy looked like in the end we had lokal working copies set to shallow checkouts. We now only work with TortoiseSVN and all is fine.

Answer (score 3):

This would happen if the working copy is [sparse](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) (a.k.a. shallow, non-recursive).  Perhaps that is the problem.

You can tell if a working copy is non-recursive by running `svn info` on it and looking for a line like `Depth: immediates`.  Normal working copies will not have this line.

Comment: Worth looking at how a client is configured -- we purposely didn't check things out with sparse.  Will keep looking.